# Does F# have the same definitions of type and data constructors as Haskell?

Tags: f#

While reading [the excellent introduction to recursive types](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recursive-types-and-folds/) from Scott Wlaschin I noticed that he is referring to case constructor for Book in the following discriminated union definition as a type constructor.

```
type Gift =
    | Book of Book
    | Chocolate of Chocolate 
    | Wrapped of Gift * WrappingPaperStyle
    | Boxed of Gift 
    | WithACard of Gift * message:string
```

Under the section:

> The relationship between the type constructors and the handlers

Scott says:

> The Gift.Book constructor takes a Book and returns a Gift

Where `Book` is:

```
type Book = {title: string; price: decimal}
```

To me, this sounds like a data constructor, not a type constructor.
Interestingly, the term data constructor is used only once in the F# language specification [here](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf) and I cannot find any descriptions of it in the same doc.

Are these concepts clearly defined in F#? Am I wrong to think the post above should be referring to a data constructor instead of a type constructor?

Comment: Can you point to where `Book` is called a "type constructor" exactly? When I search that page for the words "type constructor", I only get one hit in the header of the section "The relationship between the type constructors and the handlers"

Comment: I did not say Book is called a type constructor. It is Gift.Book I'm referring to. The content under that header, especially the bit I quoted (The Gift.Book constructor...) makes me think Gift.Book is what Scott is referring to as type constructor.

Comment: Well, it says "the Gift.Book constructor", not "the Gift.Book type constructor". And yet, in your question you say "referring to case constructor for Book in the following discriminated union definition as a type constructor". Clearly, the question's premise is false.

Comment: I disagree. It would be a great help if you could comment why that particular section heading is using the term 'type constructor'. That would help correct the misunderstanding if one exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To describe [SUM types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) in Haskell you do:

```
data Mytype = Yes | No
```

and your refer to it as a data type where `Yes` is a data constructor.

in F# you do:

```
type MyType = Yes | No
```

and you refer to it as a [discriminated union](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/discriminated-unions/) and `Yes` as union case and also as a (union) case constructor.

In both cases we're referring to algebraic data types.